# Is there a way to group columns with the same field name for columnGroupingModel for MUI's DataGrid table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I'm trying to implement a table using MUI's DataGrid, where I want to group the columns by a dynamic value at the top and have the children be the same for every group. Something like this:
[image]

Right now I have the `columnGroupingModel` list like this:

```
[{'groupId': 'Category 1', 'children': [{'field': 'osa_supplier'}, {'field': 'osa_category'}]}, {'groupId': 'Cateogry 2', 'children': [{'field': 'osa_supplier'}, {'field': 'osa_category'}]}, ...]
```

But I get the error: `Error: MUI: columnGroupingModel contains duplicated field column field osa_supplier occurs two times in the grouping model: Category 1, Category 2`.

I'm guessing the grouping functionality is only for the column names and not actually the data, so the columns must be unique, but is there a workaround so that I can do what I need or something similar? Or maybe there's another feature I'm missing that actually does what I need?

Any help would be appreciated!